# WSO2 BPS environment variable

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

does anybody know how to define static variable in WSO2 BPS that could be accessible for all processes in current BPS installation. 
I tried to define property in registry but I'm unable to read its value in process instance. 
I also know that I can define variable in deploy.xml but it will be per peocess not for all preocesses. 
Below is picture showing defined property in WSO2 BPS Management Console. 
Can someone help me with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For BPEL, you can use [Property Reader Extension](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/BPEL+Property+Reader+Extension).